# program gets stuck when sending email via gmail

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, smtplib

I have the following python function:

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 465  # For SSL

password = "valid password"
context = ssl.create_default_context()


def sendEmail(to_email, subject, content):
    from_email = "valid_email@zaliczenie.pl"
    message = (f"Tresc zadania: {content}",)
    try:
        print("connecting")
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
            print("connected")
            server.login("tmp_email@gmail.com", password)
            print("logged")
            server.sendmail(
                to_addrs=to_email,
                from_addr=from_email,
                msg=message,
            )
            print("sent")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)
```

And here are the logs:

```
connecting
connected
logged
```

So it connects, logs into google mail, but gets stuck when trying to send an email.

What am I missing?

I allowed the less safe applications and password is the one generated from google security 2FA tab (App passwords).

[image]

Comment: Is `zaliczenie.pl` a Gmail domain?  Have you turned on smtplib's debugging to see the trace of what IT sees?

Comment: no I did not. I'll try that